# Storing Enum custom Values with JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an enum:

```
public enum NotificationType {

    OPEN("open"),
    CLOSED("closed");

    public String value;

    NotificationType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I want to pass the custom string `open` or `closed` rather than `OPEN` or `CLOSED` to entity. Currently, I've mapped it in the entity as follows:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private NotificationType notificationType;
```

Which is the best way to store/ fetch enum value?

Comment: You can use a custom converter that internally builds a `NotificationType` from your `value`, since `NotificationType.valueOf(String)` is case sensitive. (This implies you still keep the enum type in your entity but have a custom value persisted in the database.)

Comment: Did you try to save with your mentioned configuration. I think it should work fine.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom [converter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) like this:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class NotificationTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<NotificationType, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(NotificationType notificationType) {
        return notificationType == null
                ? null
                : notificationType.value;
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationType convertToEntityAttribute(String code) {
        if (code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return Arrays.stream(NotificationType.values())
                .filter(c -> c.value.equals(code))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

And perhaps you'll need to remove annotation from your `notificationType` field so that this converter takes effect.

Comment: If used frequently, i would also recommend to cache values of `NotificationType` in a `Map` to reduce the stream overhead.

Comment: @Glains yes, and I would move it to a method in the enum itself, that would take a string and return the enum

Comment: Thanks Kartik and glains, I tried to use AttributeConverter but i want to pass string value to jpa

Comment: @VanithaV that's what the `convertToDatabaseColumn` method above is doing - converting enum to string and passing it on to the persistence layer for storage

Answer (score 2):

Yes, basically you have to develop a custom converter for that but I suggest you use **Optional** to avoid dealing with `null` and `exceptions`.

Add in `NotificationType`:

```
public static Optional<NotificationType> getFromValue(String value) {
   return Optional.ofNullable(value)
                  .flatMap(dv -> Arrays.stream(NotificationType.values())
                                    .filter(ev -> dv.equals(ev.value))
                                    .findFirst());
}
```

Create the required converter:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;    

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class NotificationTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<NotificationType, String> {

   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(NotificationType notificationType) {
      return null == notificationType ? null : notificationType.value;
   }

   @Override
   public NotificationType convertToEntityAttribute(String databaseValue) {
      return NotificationType.getFromValue(databaseValue)
                             .orElse(null);
   }
 }
```

And now, you only have to modify your model:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity {

   @Convert(converter=NotificationTypeConverter.class)
   private NotificationType notificationType;
}
```